# Change width of text input with button instead of focus

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have an input box that expands when it is clicked but I want to be able to use a button instead of focus to change the size.

I have tried changing the css with jquery but it does not work?

```
$('#q').css('width','100%');
```

Sample code to change with focus

```css
input[name=q]{
  width:180px;     /* NEEDED */
  transition:0.3s; -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
}
input[name=q]:focus{
  width:320px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id ="q" name="q" type="text">
```

Its probably simple but I am hitting a brick wall, thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to change the size of the `input` when you click the `button`, here's how it would work:

```js
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("q").style.width = "320px";
}
```

```css
input[name=q]{
  width:180px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<input id ="q" name="q" type="text">
<button id="button">Click here</button>
```

The JavaScript code above looks for a `button` click (using the `onclick` event) and then changes the size of the `input` whenever that happens.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply add styles like this
`` $(`#q`).css('width','320px') ``

but there is a better method
make a class with all the styles you need and use it for this element
I used `toggleClass()` here but there is also `addClass()`  and `removeClass()`

You can use `onclick` to make the button execute a function

```js
function changeq(){
  $(`#q`).toggleClass('big')
}
```

```css
input[name=q]{
  width:180px;     /* NEEDED */
  transition:0.3s; -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
}

input.big{
  width:320px ;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id ="q" name="q" type="text">
<button onclick="changeq()">change</button>
```